# Guzzle: Redirects in Pool results in 'error'. How can I tell guzzle to follow redirects?

Tags: php, redirect, guzzle

I'm using a pool to call a number of urls and I'm having some trouble with redirects.

I would expect that a redirect would be followed 'below the surface', and the new url would then be called as if it was defined in $requests. What I'm seeing, is that a redirect (both 302 or 301) is being handelled by the 'error' part, and if I lookup the error code in the 'error' option-code, it gives 301 or 302.

How can I tell guzzle to follow redirects?

Some relevant code I'm using:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$options = [
    'pool_size' => 3,

    'complete' => function (\GuzzleHttp\Event\CompleteEvent $event) {
        .......
    },
    'error' => function (\GuzzleHttp\Event\ErrorEvent $event)  {
        .........
    },

];

\GuzzleHttp\Pool::send($client, $requests, $options);
```

Comment: Redirects are handled by the Redirect Subscriber - which itself hooks into Guzzles event system but only subscribes to the "complete" event (see https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/5.2.0/src/Subscriber/Redirect.php). What does the error message say? First guess would be something like too many redirects.

Comment: See my comment on https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1013#issuecomment-87661541 (it does not fit this box)

Comment: There no mention of the error message. Please check `$event->getError();` in your error handler